# Android Wear: can't send DataItem from Wearable to Phone

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to send a DataItem from my wearable to the phone, during the Wearable splash screen activity:

```
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Wearable.getDataClient(context).putDataItem(putDataRequest)
    }
```

(`putDataRequest` is properly constructed, and includes a timestamp field so that the data is changing on each call)

The `onComplete` callback from `putDataItem` indicates a successful send.

On the phone side, I've implemented a `WearableListenerService`, with the correct intent filter in the AndroidManifest.

When the wearable calls `putDataItem`, I see the following in the logs on the phone:

```
11-04 16:46:47.320  2518  4141 W ChimeraUtils: Module com.google.android.gms.gcm has empty metadata display_name_string_id
11-04 16:46:47.338 17648 17648 I GCM     : Message from 745476177629
11-04 16:46:47.338 17648 17648 E GCM     : Dropping message to GMS from 745476177629 as no component is set
```

It appears that the phone is getting some sort of message from the wearable, but it is not recognized and so gets dropped.  My `WearableListenerService.onDataChanged` callback on the phone never gets called.

I've verified that package name, version, and signing key are identical between phone and wearable apps.

Google searches for the log messages have not been fruitful.  Does anyone know why my wearable Data Layer messages aren't getting synched to the phone app?

Edit to add: I am able to communicate between the watch and the phone if I use the `sendMessage()` API - indeed that is what I am trying to replace here, since `sendMessage` isn't reliably waking my app up when the phone is in a low-power state.

*** Edit ***
Adding some additional context as requested

Intent Filter:

```
        <service android:name=".wearable.MessageListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGE"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED"/>
                <data android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/request_response" android:scheme="wear"/>
                <data android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/wearable_app_status" android:scheme="wear"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Mobile-side receiver:

```
public class MessageListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MessageListenerService.class.getName();
    public static final String WEARABLE_APP_STATUS_PATH = "/wearable_app_status";



    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDataChanged");
        for (DataEvent event : dataEventBuffer) {
            if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
                DataItem item = event.getDataItem();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "dataItem URI = " + item.getUri());
                if (item.getUri().getPath().equals(WEARABLE_APP_STATUS_PATH)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WearableIntentService.class);
                    startService(intent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

putDataRequest on wearable

```
public static final String WEARABLE_APP_STATUS_PATH = "/wearable_app_status";

...

DataMap dataMap = new DataMap();
dataMap.putLong(DataApiConstants.WEARABLE_APP_OPEN_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());

PutDataMapRequest putDataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create(WEARABLE_APP_STATUS_PATH);
putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putAll(dataMap);
PutDataRequest putDataRequest = putDataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();
putDataRequest.setUrgent();
Log.d(LOG_TAG,"putDataRequest.getUri() == " + putDataRequest.getUri());
Task<DataItem> dataItemTask = Wearable.getDataClient(context).putDataItem(putDataRequest);
final String sender = "wearable";

dataItemTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataItem>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataItem> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataItem dataItem = task.getResult();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("Successfully sent data from %s to data layer.", sender));
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DataItem uri is " + dataItem.getUri());
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("Failed to send data from %s to data layer.", sender));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide your mobile intent-filter , your mobile side receiver and also your putDataRequest?

Comment: edited the question with more details